# How to make a command run based on if conditions are met?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So...I'm trying to get my clear cache statements to run if my BufferPoolCommitMemoryGB variable is greater than 14.99. Is my syntax even correct? Thanks in advance !

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
PhysicalMemoryGB Decimal (20, 2),
BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB Decimal (20, 2),  
BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB Decimal (20, 2),
MinServerMemoryGB Decimal (20, 2),
MaxServerMemoryGB Decimal (20, 2),
TotalServerMemoryMB Decimal (20, 2)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #TempTable (PhysicalMemoryGB, BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB,          BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB, MinServerMemoryGB, MaxServerMemoryGB,   TotalServerMemoryMB)


SELECT CAST(physical_memory_in_bytes / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL (20, 2)) AS PhysicalMemoryGB,
CAST ((bpool_committed * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL (20, 2)) AS BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB,
CAST ((bpool_commit_target * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL (20, 2) AS BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB,

(
SELECT CAST(CAST(value_in_use AS INT) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(20, 2))
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'min server memory (MB)'
) AS MinServerMemoryGB,

(
SELECT CAST(CAST(value_in_use AS INT) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(20, 2))
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'max server memory (MB)'
) AS MaxServerMemoryGB,



(
SELECT cntr_value / 1024.0
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name = 'Total Server Memory(KB)'
) AS TotalServerMemoryMB
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info WITH(NOLOCK);

DECLARE @PhysicalMemoryGB DECIMAL(20, 2),
@BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB DECIMAL(20, 2),
@BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB DECIMAL(20, 2),
@MinServerMemoryGB DECIMAL (20, 2),
@MaxServerMemoryGB DECIMAL (20, 2),
@TotalServerMemoryMB DECIMAL (20, 2)

BEGIN

IF @BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB > 14.99
THEN 
DBCC FreeProcCache
DBCC FreeSystemCache
DBCC FreeSessionCache

END 

DROP Table #TempTable

END
```

Is my syntax (especially for the IF statement) even correct? What am I doing wrong? The reason I'm a little confused is I do not know what the 2nd conditional statement should be if the GB is not above 14.99

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you test it? did you even bother looking for syntax of the if statement? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: If you're going to edit your question and change the code from an `IF` to `CASE WHEN` then why not edit the text of the question along with the code change?  That syntax simply does not apply.  Go back to trying `IF`.

Comment: Someone told me the IF was wrong....ill switch it back . I've tried the IF before and it did not work.

Comment: @JohnLoe you have to define "did not work" more specifically. did you get an error message? If so, what was the exact error message you got? Also tag my name so I know when you've responded.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different problems here.

Firstly, the syntax of your `IF...` block is incorrect. It should be

```
IF @BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB > 14.99
BEGIN
 DBCC FreeProcCache
 DBCC FreeSystemCache
 DBCC FreeSessionCache
END
```

(`BEGIN` not `THEN`)

There's also a syntax error in the `SELECT` statement which inserts values into the temp table:

```
CAST ((bpool_commit_target * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL (20, 2)) AS BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB,
```

(missing `)` before `AS BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB`)

But that won't fix the query; in the `IF` block you're testing the value of a variable (`@BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB`) to which no value is assigned. Either you need to set a value for `@BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB` before you test it, or perhaps (and I'm guessing your intent here), test the value from the temp table directly:

```
IF (SELECT BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB FROM #TempTable) > 14.99
```

Without knowing the specifics of the situation you're trying to address, I'd be inclined to suggest that flushing the entire buffer pool might not be a great idea; there are probably query plans and data pages in the cache which might be best kept there.

- Have you looked into the [`optimize for ad hoc workloads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) setting?
- Kalen Delaney wrote an article on [clearing plans for adhoc SQL statements from the cache](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-adhoc-workloads-and-clearing-the-single-use-plan-cache-bloat/) which might be useful.

Comment: Wow, is there any way I can pay you back?thanks so much for the extensive reply!

Comment: in the mean time are there any resources you would recommend I use to brush up my skills/knowledge base?

Comment: @JohnLoe - on StackExchange sites like StackOverflow, you can upvote an answer if it's useful to you. Since you asked this question, you can also accept an answer as correct. That's thanks enough!